# Why doesn't this html template render the scraped website data in the web browser(Python, Flask, HTML, Web-Scraping)?

Tags: python, html, flask, web-scraping

Whenever I print out the scraped data in the terminal it shows the scraped data fine, but whenever I try serve it using Python Flask, the HTML template that I'm using does not render the data in the web browser. If you could help me fix this code.

Python (Flask) file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

src = requests.get('https://webscraper.netlify.app/').text


scraper = BS(src, 'lxml')

# head = scraper.find('main').select_one('article:nth-of-type(4)').div.text
# author = scraper.find('main').select_one('p').text

head = scraper.body.header.h1.text

snd_author = scraper.body.main.select_one('article:nth-of-type(2)').p.text

fst_article = scraper.body.main.article.div


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML (view) file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2.0"/>
    <title>Python Flask Web Scraper</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Python Flask Variables go here: -->
    
    <h1> {{ head }} </h1>

    <p>{{ snd_author }}</p>
    
    <article>{{ fst_article }}</article>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use:

```
return render_template('index.html', head=head, snd_author=snd_author, fst_article=fst_article)
```